# Printing tibbles in iESS with many columns extremely slow

Tags: ess, r

When I print large tibbles from R it takes a *very* long time and the iESS buffer runs extremely slowly thereafter (huge lag moving the cursor throughout the buffer or typing).  The code below takes 5 minutes to finish printing whereas in Rstudio it takes a second.  I'm using ess-17.11 and the latest tidyverse installed using devtools: `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

start_time <- Sys.time()

tst_tibble <- gapminder %>%
  # change the year filter to add or subtract columns 
  # from the final tibble
  filter(year < 1975) %>% 
  unite(loc_yr, continent, country, year) %>%
  select(loc_yr, lifeExp) %>% 
  spread(loc_yr, lifeExp)

print(tst_tibble)
print(Sys.time() - start_time)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed on the ESS bug tracker at https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/474. The problem has been fixed in the tibble package. If you cannot wait for to fix to be released to CRAN you can install directly from the master branch with `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tibble")`.

Comment: Thanks! From the linked discussion I found that actually I needed to update the latest version of `pillar` as I already had the latest version of `tibble`:  `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pillar")`